# Solutions of a Linear Differential Equation in a Banach Algebra

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, banach-algebras

Assume $A$ is a real Banach algebra (which need not necessarily be commutative or finite-dimensional) with unit and the function $f: \mathbb{R}\to A$ satisfies the differential equation $$\frac{df\left( t \right)}{dt}=f\left( t \right)\cdot s\left( t \right)$$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ with a given continuous function $s: \mathbb{R}\to A$. How can you prove that $f\left( t \right)$ is invertible for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ if there is (at least) one $t_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$ for which $f\left( t_{0} \right)$ is invertible?

In case the Banach algebra is just $\mathbb{R}$ everybody knows the answer: the only function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ which then satisfies the differential equation and $f\left( t_{0} \right)=r_{0}$ with a given $r_{0}\in \mathbb{R}$ is defined by $$f\left( t \right)=r_{0}\cdot \exp\left( \int_{t_{0}}^{t}s\left( u \right)du \right)$$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ and thus the assertion ensues immediately. Virtually the same reasoning is valid if the Banach algebra is commutative (no matter whether it is finite-dimensional), only the real exponential function has to be replaced by the exponential on the Banach algebra which is defined by the power series $$\exp\left( a \right)=\sum_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{i!}\cdot a^{i}$$which is convergent for all $a\in A$, and once again, the uniquely determined function $f:A\to A$ which satisfies the differential equation and $f\left( t_{0} \right)=r_{0}$ with a given $r_{0}\in A$ is defined by $f\left( t \right)=r_{0}\cdot \exp\left( \int_{t_{0}}^{t}s\left( u \right)du \right)$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$, where it is well known how to define this integral over the continuous function $s$ with values in $A$. So, if $f\left( t_{0} \right)=r_{0}$ is invertible then $f\left( t \right)$ is invertible for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$ as this is true for $\exp\left( \int_{t_{0}}^{t}s\left( u \right)du \right)$.

Unfortunately this does not work if the Banach algebra A is not commutative because then a solution of the differential equation cannot be given explicitly using the exponential function on A.

Comment: Where is that problem coming from?

Comment: @KBS:  I was working on affine connections on a differentiable manifold which looks locally like an infinite-dimensional Banach space. If you study the parallel-transport with respect to this connection along a path locally in a chart a differential equation equation of this type arises. Moving along the path it starts with the identical mapping which is an automorphism of the Banach space and it should stay so moving on. The non-commutative Banach algebra involved here is the continuous linear operators on the Banach space (= the tangent spaces in the chart along the path), of course.

Comment: Does that generalize from the matrix-valued case? I mean, from studying the time evolution of an invertibility test?

Comment: I'm probably missing something, why doesn't the exponential still produce a solution in noncommutative case? It works for matrices, if I remember correctly.

Comment: @lisyarus The exponential works in the matrix case only if the matrix-valued function describing the dynamics commute with itself at all possible times; i.e. $f(t_1)f(t_2)=f(t_2)f(t_1)$.

Comment: @KBS Ahh, I see, it makes sense, thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $f'(t)=f(t)s(t)$, $a:=f(t_0)$ invertible. Consider the IVP
$g'(t)=-s(t)g(t)$, $g(t_0)=a^{-1}$. Then for all $t$
$$
(fg)'(t)=f'(t)g(t)+f(t)g'(t)= f(t)s(t)g(t)-f(t)s(t)g(t)=0
$$
and $f(t_0)g(t_0)=1$ ($1$ the unit in $A$). Thus $f(t)g(t)=1$ for all $t$.
So we have a right inverse for all time. Consider $f$ for example to the right $(t \ge t_0)$: The set of invertible elements is open hence $f(t)$ is invertible on an interval $[t_0,T)$. Then $g(t)=f(t)^{-1}$ $(t \in [t_0,T))$. Assume $f(T)$ is not invertible. Then $\|f^{-1}(t)\|=\|g(t)\|$ is unbounded on $[t_0,T)$, a contradiction. Thus $f$ stays invertible on $t \ge t_0$. The case $t \le t_0$ should by similar.

Comment: There can be no doubt about your proof that there exists a right inverse on all of $\mathbb{R}$. But I cannot quite understand your argument why the inverse should get unbounded in $\left[ t_{0},T \right]$ only because it ceases to exist at $T$. Can you explain?

Comment: If $(x_n)$ is a sequence of invertible elements in a Banach algebra which is convergent with limit $y$, say, and $y$ is not invertible, then it is known that $\|x_n^{-1}\| \to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. For a proof see for example Lemma 10.17 in W. Rudin: Functional Analysis, McGraw-Hill, 1973

Comment: Yes, just looked up Rudin's proof. Had not been aware that this holds for any Banach algebra. Clever combination of two independent arguments, so the problem is solved. Great!